# Android Studio wrong drawable preview with layer-list

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable

### The issue

I made a simple drawable in Android Studio 1.1.0 (see code below). It is a white rounded rectangle with a black margin. The drawable is rendered as expected in my app. Only the drawable preview in Android Studio messes it up.
Here is the picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdAEy.png

Instead of the expected result, a dark rectangle is shown in the preview. It seems to me that the `<layer-list>` is not fully rendered.

---

Why is this happening? Is it just a bug in Android Studio or am I doing something wrong? Any way to fix this?

### The code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#555555"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="0.5dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="0.5dp" android:right="0.5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="4.5dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: A sidebar comment - you'll have much better luck ignoring the previewer altogether and simply focusing on the XML.

Comment: This happens to other drawables as well. It's quite annoying sometimes.